# How to backup/set up copy of the Umbraco production site on your local environment

Tags: umbraco

How do I migrate existing Umbraco website on to my local environment. I have the source code folder of the existing website and I copy pasted them into a fresh Umbraco website but I run into database issues like "umbraco cannot connect to database"  and web server issue like "the web server is configured to not list the content of this directory". My IIS is running alright.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you're hosting your Umbraco website, the reason for not being able to connect to the database when on local environment, could be that your connectionstring is configured with the SQL server as "localhost", or could be that the server hosting the site is configured to block external connections to the SQL server.

If you're able to connect to the SQL Server using SQL Management Studio, you can generate a SQL script with schema + data and run this on a local SQL Server, then in Umbraco's web.config, you'll reconfigure the ConnectionString to connect to your local SQL Server.

As for the "The web server is configured to not list the content of this directory" - it sounds like ASP.NET may not be installed, as it's trying to do a filebrowse rather than run the server-side code. Have a look at https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Requirements/index-v7 for Umbraco's hosting requirements.